# excel to database - convert colums and row matches to database format

Tags: database, excel, format

Apologies for badly worded question.

I have the below table in excel:

[image]

The real file is 800 colums wide and 2800 rows deep so over 2 million combinations. more over its really difficult to manage in a database.

I need to convert the data to a database friendly format, something like:

[image]

Being honest I have no idea where to start. is there a reverse pivot in excel or an existing script to do this?

so logic, where row meets column in excel, fetch value and write all three to a database format.

any pointers?

Thanks as always

Comment: Thanks pnuts, didn't even know what to call it so thought I would get some pointers here and you have given me just that. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code to create a csv file that you can then import into the database of your choice.  I tested it on a dataset of similar size to the one you described and it completed in about 30 seconds.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim strTemp As String

    arrData = Range("A1", Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Value

    Close #1
    Open "C:\Temp\ExcelData.csv" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Product,Customer,Price"
    For rIndex = 2 To UBound(arrData, 1)
        For cIndex = 2 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            strLine = vbNullString
            For i = 1 To 3
                strTemp = Choose(i, arrData(rIndex, 1), arrData(1, cIndex), arrData(rIndex, cIndex))
                If InStr(1, strTemp, ",", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then strTemp = """" & strTemp & """"
                strLine = strLine & "," & strTemp
            Next i
            Print #1, Mid(strLine, 2)
        Next cIndex
    Next rIndex
    Close #1

    Erase arrData

End Sub
```

Comment: if I had a `customer account name` in column b, How would I be able to output it to my results as well. `Print #1, "Product,Customer,account,Price" where 'account' is column B? Thanks again,
`

Comment: You would change cIndex to start at 3 instead of 2, and you would change the i to go from 1 to 4, and then for the third choice you would put arrData(rIndex, 2) and shift the arrData(rIndex, cIndex) over to the 4th choice.

Comment: how to shift to 4th place?`strTemp = Choose(i, arrData(rIndex, 1), arrData(1, cIndex), arrData(rIndex, cIndex))` THanks, just need to try process all this :-)

Comment: `strTemp = Choose(i, arrData(rIndex, 1), arrData(1, cIndex), arrData(rIndex, 2), arrData(rIndex, cIndex))`

Comment: ah, okay thanks 100%. I need to work this out and try understand it though, you too sharp for me :-) thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the transpose function for this purpose.